# Links in javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have some dynamically created links in  my pages and what I need to do is when I click on the link, I should pass the name of the link to another page. So, please show me a way to accomplish this. Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Can you explain more detalied what you want to do? What means "should pass the name of the link to another page"?

Comment: When I said name of the link i.e <a href = "some website">Name_of_the_link</a> . This is name of the link !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [jquery](http://jquery.com), you can use :

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#foo">foo</a> <a href="#bar">bar</a>
<script>
  $('a').click(function () { alert($(this).text()); /* attr('href') */ });
</script>
</html>
```

Of course the html an so are not good, but the click thing is what you need.
Then you could use ajax, or a parameter in the target URL to give the link to the other page.

But why don't you generate that when creating links?
I mean add a `href="mylink?from=mylink"`.

Edit: corrected with your comment. What you need is `text()` rather than `attr('href')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('anchor').innerHTML;
```

then you can pass this value as a parameter, to another page.

Answer (score 1):

```
documetn.getElementById("mylink").setAttribute("href", "newlink");
documetn.getElementById("mylink").InnerHTML = "new link name";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var link = document.getElementById('link');
link.setAttribute("href", link.getAttribute("href") + "?linkName=" + encodeURI(link.innerHTML));
```

This will make your link be something like this:

```
<a id="link" href="http://somewebsite.com?linkName=Name_of_the_link">Name_of_the_link</a>
```

Then on the "other" page you can access the link name through the GET variable `linkName`.